# Preview Crashes when passing arguments to subView

Tags: swift

I am drawing simple y-axis on top of a chart in SwiftUI. The y-axis is defined as a View that takes the yMin and yMax as input.

When i try this with dummy data it works fine. But when i include this in a view
which fetches data from an API call and has an 'onAppear' attached to a VStack it works
if i add one of yMin defined by the data but not when i add both the yMin and yMax at the same time.  The code looks like this

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct TestGraph: View{

let apipath = "http://xyz"
@ObservedObject private var myViewModel = MyViewModel()

var body: some View {
   VStack {
        ZStack {
         let yMax = self.myViewModel.data.map(\.Price).max() ?? 0.0
         let yMin = self.myViewModel.data.map(\.Price).min() ?? 0.0

         let yMax2 = CGFloat(yMax)
         let yMin2 = CGFloat(yMin)


         yAxisLabels(yMax: yMax, yMin: yMin)

         LineGraph(dataPoints: self.myViewModel.data.map{CGFloat($0.Price)}

      }
   }
   .onAppear {self.myViewModel.fetchData(apiURL: apipath)}
 }
}
```

when i hardcode the yMax and yMin, or even just hardcode one of them

```
yAxisLabels(yMax: 138.0, yMin: yMin)
```

or

```
yAxisLabels(yMax: 138.0, yMin: 108)
```

or

```
yAxisLabels(yMax: yMax, yMin: 108)
```

then it works. But when i use

```
yAxisLabels(yMax: yMax, yMin: yMin)
```

the Preview Crashes without any Error in the code.

This is the code for the yAxisLabels code.

```
struct yAxisLabels: View {
    var yMax: CGFloat = 141.0
    var yMin: CGFloat = 25.25
    
    var body: some View {
//        let yrange = ymax - ymin
//        let yvalue = ymin + ((yrange)/5).rounded()
//        let yvalueChart = (1.0 - (yvalue-ymin)/yrange) * 200.0
        let yRange = yMax-yMin
        let yRatio1 = (yRange/5.0).rounded()
        let yRatio2 = yRatio1 / yRange
        let yOffset2 = (yMin.rounded() - yMin) / yRange
        let y0 = yMin.rounded() + yRatio1
        let y1 = yMin.rounded() + 2.0*yRatio1
        let y2 = yMin.rounded() + 3.0*yRatio1
        let y3 = yMin.rounded() + 4.0*yRatio1

        GeometryReader { GeometryProxy in
            Text("\(y0, specifier: "%.1f")")
                .font(.caption)
                .offset(x: 8, y: GeometryProxy.size.height*(1-yOffset2-1*yRatio2))
            Text("\(y1, specifier: "%.1f")")
                .font(.caption)
                .offset(x: 8, y: GeometryProxy.size.height*(1-yOffset2-2*yRatio2))
            Text("\(y2, specifier: "%.1f")")
                .font(.caption)
                .offset(x: 8, y: GeometryProxy.size.height*(1-yOffset2-3*yRatio2))
            Text("\(y3, specifier: "%.1f")")
                .font(.caption)
                .offset(x: 8, y: GeometryProxy.size.height*(1-yOffset2-4*yRatio2))
        }
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?